Why not just set Django's ALLOWED_HOSTS to ["*"]?
I understand why validation of the host header is important but I do not understand why this would be the responsibility of Django.
The docs for the settings mysteriously mention

which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations.

and the docs for the host header validation mention something similar:

Because even seemingly-secure web server configurations are susceptible to fake Host headers

and

Previous versions of this document recommended configuring your web server to ensure it validates incoming HTTP Host headers. While this is still recommended, in many common web servers a configuration that seems to validate the Host header may not in fact do so. For instance, even if Apache [..]


In 2024, is there still any reason to fear these "many" (undocumented) "seemingly-safe server configurations" or can I just use a sane proxy server and let that do the validation instead? Setting ALLOWED_HOSTS to ["*"] removes one more thing to think about while deploying.

Edit to self-answer (at least partly): setting up a 'catch all' for SSL may be "somewhat hard", as e.g. documented here for nginx. This in turn may mean a site gets traffic that's not meant for it.

Professional Paranoia!
If you are operating in an environment where the Django server is exposed to the entire internet, there are hostile actors out there. If you can define a subset of possible addresses as ones you want to serve, you immediately reduce the threat profile. If you are operating behind some sort of firewall or proxy which ought to repel such threats, it doesn't hurt to assume that it might be failing to fulfill its duties.

I suppose "defense in depth" is a fair answer... but this still makes me wonder what these "many" (undocumented) "seemingly-safe server configurations" would be
